# Why was Haldir in command of the Rivendell army?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium, the-two-towers

From Wikipedia:

> Soon after, however, a large group of the Elves of Lórien join the
> defences. Elrond, at the prompting of Galadriel, sends the Elves under
> the command of Haldir of Lórien to reinforce the defence of the keep.

Haldir is clearly some kind of a Captain or a commander under Galadriel, not Elrond.
[image]

[image]

I only noticed this after my 10th viewing of The Two Towers so a few questions came to my mind:

1. Why would Elrond send an army from Rivendell under the command of Haldir? This doesn't really make any sense to me except perhaps that Peter Jackson wanted to reuse an existing and familiar character.
2. What actually happens in the books? It's a very long time since I've read them and I have absolutely no memory about these events.

Comment: This doesn't happen in the books. The likely explanation is that the elves are from Lorien sent by Gladariel at the prompting of Elrond. Again, not in the books.

Comment: Heh, I am sorry for the dupe, I saw the title when searching for the topic but it was misleading so I didn't actually open it. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the books the Elves of Lórien (and of the Woodland Realm) were too busy defending their own borders, and other Elves would be too far away (Lindon and Rivendell) or too few (Rivendell again) to intervene. So none of them were in a position to help Rohan or anyone else.

Comment: Makes sense. I can't really blame Jackson for putting it in though, it's a cool moment in the movie.

Answer (score 1):

> "But there are some of us still who go abroad for the gathering of news and the watching of our enemies, and they speak the languages of other lands. I am one. Haldir is my name."
>   -- Haldir in The Fellowship of the Ring, Book II, Chp. 6 "Lothlórien"

It's plausible that Elrond supplied the troops but wisely placed them under Haldir's command:

1. As a part of his charge to defend Lórien, Haldir would be familiar with the terrain of nearby Rohan and Helm's Deep. The books state he was well-traveled outside of Lórien.
   Rivendell however is far to the North and on the other side of the Misty Mountains.
2. While the force of men defending Helm's Deep are under the command of King Théoden, Elrond and Galadriel's primary purpose for sending troops is to reinforce Aragorn, Rohan's leader on the ground and the one the elves are putting their faith in to assume the vacant throne of Gondor. Haldir and his brothers escorted the Fellowship through the forest previously, so Aragorn and Haldir have some history and familiarity with each other. Maybe not a lot, but certainly more then any of the [Wilhelms in shiny elf armor](https://youtu.be/wWvK4NMgx8U?t=8s). Aragorn is clearly relieved to see him in the film:

   [image: Haldir and Aragorn]

A side note: when Haldir states he brings "word from Elrond of Rivendell" that doesn't mean he personally spoke with Elrond. Whoever marched the detachment from Rivendell could have served as the courier to Haldir (or Galadriel herself, since she and Elrond communicate telepathically). When he arrives at Helm's Deep, Haldir relays the message to Aragorn as the latest link in the chain, but not necessarily the only one.

So there you go: Haldir knows the land, the language and the leader. Makes perfect strategic sense for him to command.

Too bad he got his unit annihilated...  :-/ 
[image: Many elves died to bring us this information]

Comment: 'It's plausible that Elrond supplied the troops but wisely placed them under Haldir's command' And it stupidly leaves Lórien unguarded when it's being assaulted. Not to mention endangering the lives of the elves when they are headed to battle far away.